# Java Text Parser with customized open and closing tags?

Tags: java

I am looking for a simple java Text parser that parses a piece of text just like a XML SAX parser but with customized open and closing tags. Instead of "<" I have to deal with "[".

Which one can I use, or do I have to make some myself?
Example text:

```
[hlpLnk key=hlpId]some text and [lnk key=PrfS]products[/lnk] and some more text[/hlpLnk]
```

Comment: If you need to do that quick and dirty, wouldn't it be simple just to replace the '[' and ']' for '<'and '>', and the use any xml parser?

Comment: I thought about that, but not possible as the above text can be part of a XML document as XML content. As such, that above should be parsed as a kind of post XML processing.

Comment: Well I think it still applies... for example, if it is part of an xml, let's say a value for any DOM element or maybe a CDATA section, you will need two phases: First you would parse the outer xml with any xml parser, and then you would obtain this document/value to be parsed with your custom parser (or xml parser with those characters replaced)

Comment: True, it could be possible, but I bet there is a general text parser (like used in JavaCC) in which you can specify the opening and closing tag. However, I don't seem to find them :(

Comment: I would look into the source of the sax parser, it might be some customization possibilities

Comment: Yes, I looked in the sources of Xerces a few days ago, but got lost, it wasn't all so clear as expected.

Comment: Many templating languages have markup similar to the above with customizable tag characters (freemarker for example and handlebars.java). But if you need the AST that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a this parser on JavaWorld: [LINKE](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077493/mobile-java/java-tip-128--create-a-quick-and-dirty-xml-parser.html)
It's simple, does what I need, only need some refactoring,cleanup and testing.

And the Nano XML parser source is looking useful: clear, small, easy to read. With some changes i could use this I think. (Projects like Xerces contains a lot I don't need/want)